# How to extract integers from a string separated by spaces in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to extract integers from a string in which integers are separated by blank spaces i.e ' '. How could I do that ??

Input

```
I='1 15 163 132'
```

Result:

```
[1,15,163,132]
```

So I wrote a function which goes like this

```
def getIt(aStr):
collect = []
i=0
while i < len(aStr):
    print('i = ' + str(i))
    if aStr[i]!=' ':
        j=0
        while aStr[i+j]!=' ' or  (i+j)<=len(aStr)-1:
            print('j = '+str(j))
            j+=1
        if i+j==len(aStr):    
            collect.append(int(aStr[i:i+j-1]))
        else:
            collect.append(int(aStr[i:i+j]))
        i+=j+1

    else:
        i+=1  
return collect
```

The code runs perfectly when I remove the condition

```
while aStr[i+j]!=' ':# or  (i+j)<=len(aStr)-1:
```

And place a blank space at the end of every input string. Please inform where am I going wrong?

Comment: provide a complex example. Because `[int(i) for i in I.split()]` would produce the output you expected.

Comment: So...... did any of the answers work for you? If so, would you care to flag this post as "answered"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this code:

```
myIntegers = [int(x) for x in I.split()]
```

---

**EXPLANATION:**

---

Where **s** is the string you want to split up, and **a** is the string you want to use as the delimeter. Then:

```
s.Split(a)
```

Splits the string **s**, at those points where **a** occurs, and returns a list of sub-strings that have been split up.

If no argument is provided, eg:
    s.Split()
then it defaults to  using whitespaces (such as spaces, tabs, newlines) as the delimeter.

**Concretely, In your case:**

```
I = '1 15 163 132'
I = I.split() 
print(I)
```

> ["1", "15", "163", "132"]

It creates a list of strings, separating at those points where there is a space in your particular example.

Here is the  official python [documentation on the string split() method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split).

---

Now we use what is known as **List Comprehensions** to convert every element in a list into an integer.

```
myNewList = [operation for x in myOtherList]
```

Here is a breakdown of what it is doing:

- Assuming that *myOtherList* is a list, with some number of elements,
- then we will temporarily store one element at a time as *x*
- and we will perform some operation for each element in *myOtherList*
- assuming that this operation we perform has some return value,

  - then the returned value will be stored as an element in a new list that we are creating
- The end result is that we will populate a new list *myNewList*, that is the exact same length as *myOtherList*

**Concretely, In your case:**

```
myIntegers = [int(x) for x in I.split()]
```

**Performs the following:**

- We saw that I.split() returns ["1", "15", "163", "132"]
- for each of these string elements, simply convert them to an integer
- and store that integer as an element in a new list.

See the official python [documentation on List Comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) for more information.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: *if no argument is provided, then it defaults to using " "* isn't true - with the default being `None`, it uses **whitespace** as the delimiter as per docs... see: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

Comment: My bad, thanks for picking up on that :) I will make the necessary edit so i don't corrupt any more people.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply do like this,

```
>>> import re
>>> I='bar 1 15 foo 163 132 foo bar'
>>> [int(i) for i in I.split() if re.match(r'^\d+$', i)]
[1, 15, 163, 132]
```

**Without regex:**

```
>>> I='bar 1 15 foo 163 132 foo bar'
>>> [int(i) for i in I.split() if i.isdigit()]
[1, 15, 163, 132]
```

`i.isdigit()` returns true only for the strings which contain only digits.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
x="1 15 163 132"
print re.findall(r"[+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?",x)
```

If you have only positive integers you can simply do

```
print re.findall(r"\d+",x)

[1, 15, 163, 132]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:-

```
I='1 15 163 132'
map(int, a.split(' '))
```